# WebProxy URI is not valid

Tags: c#, webproxy

This is the code I currently have

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
    proxy.Address = new Uri(96.44.147.138:6060);
    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername.Text, proxyPassword.Text);
    proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"));
}
```

The proxy needs credentials.

I get an error on line `proxy.Address = new Uri(96.44.147.138:6060);` 
saying

> "The URI scheme is not valid."

Not sure what kind of value it's expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uri` should consist of scheme host and optiona port. So you should use

```
proxy.Address = new Uri("http://96.44.147.138:6060");
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be like;

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var proxy = new WebProxy();

    proxy.Address = new Uri("http://96.44.147.138:6060");
    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername.Text, proxyPassword.Text);
    proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;

    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"));
}
```

Example edit: [Setting a global HTTP proxy in C# and .NET client classes](http://www.hccp.org/csharp-http-proxy.html)